# Jenkins build error with message Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project

Tags: jenkins, maven-3

**Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project in Jenkins build  with error message**

[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ projectname---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 21 source files to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\projectname\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] Target option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  13.958 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-07-30T14:53:55+05:45
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] **Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Projectname: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:**
[ERROR] Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] Target option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\projectname\pom.xml to projectnamegroup/projectname/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/projectname-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE

**POM Details**

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  
  <groupId>projectnameworkgroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectnameframework</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>projecnameautomation</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 <properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>
 
  
  <build>
 <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>MYtestNG.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
</plugins>
  </build>


  <dependencies>
     
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.5</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sikuli/sikuli-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sikuli</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikuli-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.assertthat/selenium-shutterbug -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.assertthat</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-shutterbug</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.38</version>
</dependency>

   
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-clean-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/ -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>

     </dependencies>
     
 <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>mvntestngrepo.read</id>
      <url>https://github.com/abc/projectname</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>
 
</project>
```

**Looking for solution. Please give your valuable solution.Thank you**

**Used version Details**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `maven-compiler-plugin` has default 5 `source` and `target` options.
You must set explicit values to that options.
Something like this:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
  <configuration>
  <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
  <source>1.7</source>
  <target>1.7</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks alexander it worked.However, i got error with Repository write. Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project mvnprojectname: Please, give me your feedback or suggestion on it as well.

Comment: unfortunately this is beyond my experience